# Homebrew Error: No formulae found in taps

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, paramiko, tap

I'm trying to install paramiko on my MacBook Pro (OSX Sierra) without going through Xcode because I'm too lazy to install Xcode honestly.

When trying to run:

```
brew install paramiko
```

I get:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "paramiko"
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I've tried untapping home-brew via:

```
brew untap homebrew
```

And I get:

```
Error: No available tap homebrew/php.
```

Also tried:

```
brew tap --repair
brew update
```

Nothing besides:

```
Updated 1 tap (caskroom/cask).
No changes to formulae.
```

If I have to go through Xcode, that's fine but I feel the issue here is not the installation process but something weird with the taps...

Comment: Just boosting for answers.

Comment: `pip install paramiko` tried this? I'm facing the same issue and in one post someone recommended that you can also try pip3 (instead of pip), pip version may also be the cause.

Comment: You may need to do : `brew install python3` to get pip3 and then `pip3 install paramiko`

Comment: OK, I think I got it. You need pip3. For that you need Python3. You can install python3 using brew (provided you have latest or required XCode version) OR download Python3 binary for mac from their site https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2-macosx10.6.pkg and then install it. Once installed, run `pip3 install paramiko`, you'd be good.

Answer (score 82):

This worked for me.

run `brew doctor`

> Warning: Some taps are not on the default git origin branch and may
> not receive updates. If this is a surprise to you, check out the
> default branch with: git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout
> master

then run `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core)`

Comment: I used ```git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master``` and it worked

Comment: @TobiDaada I'm glad it worked for you. Could u give it a vote, it would help someone else

Comment: @Denny Just did :)

Comment: This worked for me, I was trying to install brew install maven, I was getting the "No formulae found in taps" error. I ran the command mentioned by Denny and it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Denny , what does this command do ? 
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master

Comment: `brew doctor` works with me

Answer (score 22):

Run this command:

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

this will switch to master, then run

```
brew doctor
```

this should run without any error.

If there is no error you can install anything with brew install

ex: `brew install wget`

Comment: Nice, It's worked for me.
BTW, What is wget?

Comment: this commands also helped installing redis.    
```brew install redis```

Answer (score 4):

I ran:

```
brew doctor
```

which gave me as first warning:

> Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:

```
  rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core
```

Running those 2 commands above solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue when installing Node via brew.

I fixed it by running two commands:

`$  brew doctor`

This shows me this warning:

```
Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core
```

Then I ran these two commands to fix the warning:

`$ rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"`

`$ brew tap homebrew/core`

And then I tried installing Node:

`$ brew install node`

It worked.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following approach in the following link helps.

1. Depending upon your pip/python/xcode version, brew may not work in installing python or python3.
2. I installed Python3 binary .pkg for Mac from their site, installed it on Mac.
3. Then, opened a new Terminal window and did:

which python3 && python3 --version && which pip3 && pip3 --version

pip3 install paramiko

[brew or pip - install credstash - errors - No named formulae found in taps / OSErr six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192505/brew-or-pip-install-credstash-errors-no-named-formulae-found-in-taps-ose/41192972#41192972)

Comment: this worked for the same error with a different brew install

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I also had this issue, I'm a developer.

I want to develop an OS with a command known as `i686-elf-gcc`, but with homebrew it doesn't work. So, use this:

`brew doctor`

And a warning will show up:

```
Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core
```

So run these:

`rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"`

`brew tap homebrew/core`

After that, I tried installing my package:

`brew install i686-elf-gcc`

And, it worked, it should also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub /usr/bin/pub
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/dart/bin/dart2js /usr/bin/dart2js
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23043694)

Comment: i think it's clear enough, from question seems he familiar enough also with cli, so may be no need to description.

Answer (score 0):

git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master

this command helps