# Brew is installed on mac, but the brew install maven is not working

Tags: maven, homebrew

I'm trying to install maven on my MAC, but When I run the command : brew install maven

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

My brew version is:

```
Homebrew 3.2.3-59-gb18bbac
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision b18bbacce; last commit 2021-07-21)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 1a48b289dc; last commit 2021-07-23)
```

Comment: try this:

run brew doctor

look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113448/homebrew-error-no-formulae-found-in-taps

Comment: I already tried that, but the problem persists.

Comment: What do you get when you run the `brew search maven` command?

Comment: I get:
`==> Casks
mavensmate
homebrew/cask-fonts/font-maven-pro
homebrew/cask-fonts/font-maven-pro-vf-beta`