# How to install Maven on OS-Big Sur (ideally w/ homebrew; both docs not working)

Tags: maven, homebrew, macos-big-sur, homebrew-cask

I have never had such a hard time in my life doing something like this, I have downloaded and unzipped and set the paths manually, i.e. below:

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/coolguy/Desktop/apache-maven-3.8.1 
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Just as the maven docs illustrate yet continually I get 'maven' not found, even when cd'ing into the bin folder. `mvn -ver` - I have done this multiple times, and continuously keyword not found.

I'd actually prefer to do it via homebrew, and I have tried that multiple times as well; but continuously the steps do not work. Is this a big sur thing?

```
cameron@cool-guy-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew install maven

Updating Homebrew...
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/cask and adoptopenjdk/openjdk).
==> New Casks
trezor-suite
==> Updated Casks
Updated 17 casks.

Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "maven".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Any tips greatly appreciated.

**Note:** My java version is:

```
java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
```

---

**UPDATE**, 2 more attempts in .bash_profile:

Now, I have .bash_profile as below: (moved folder to apps folder via tutorial).

```
export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

**Still *mvn* not found..**

Have also tried using just the below:

```
PATH=/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3bin:$PATH
```

**Still *mvn* not found..**

Why is this insanely difficult?

Comment: Remove all the M2* Env variables only the entry in `PATH=Users/coolguy/Desktop/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin:$PATH` is needed. Where have you added this entry? `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Yes, in .bash_profile

Comment: I just tried the above via a youtube video.. still dead mvn keyword. let me try using your one liner pointing to apps folder.

Comment: I had the same issue trying to install maven through homebrew. If it is still relevant  the workaround is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113448/homebrew-error-no-formulae-found-in-taps
So, the issue is in homebrew itself. There are all the actions in a nutshell:
1 `brew doctor`
2 `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master`
3 `brew install maven` (will install the last available openjdk + maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the `M2_HOME`, `M2` come from, can you ensure `maven` command exists in the path you added? If you're not familiar with shell `PATH`, just don't touch it.

1. Remove all the `M2` related variables
2. Install `maven` with Homebrew: `brew install maven`