# Install libgdiplus on M1

Tags: .net, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install libgdiplus on M1 MacBook. OS version 12 Monterey.

When I do `brew install mono-libgdiplus` it shows below message on terminal.

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "mono-libgdiplus".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research I found I needed to do `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master`to fix the issue.

Check this link for more details: [Homebrew Error: No formulae found in taps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113448/homebrew-error-no-formulae-found-in-taps)

Comment: This fixed it for me on an M1 mac (not sure if it was related).

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

```
$ brew search mono-libgdiplus
==> Formulae
mono-libgdiplus
```

And homebrew-core does [have the bottles](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mono-libgdiplus.rb#L10-L11) for monterey and big sur.